# Issue with paper-dialog size in Polymer v1.X

Tags: css, polymer-1.0

I have following paper-dialog sekeleton setup inside one of my custom element.

```
<paper-dialog id="error_dialog">
   <h2>{{error_message}}</h2>
   <p>{{error_detail}}</p>
</paper-dialog>
```

as and when I get any error I update the values of "error_message" and "error_detail" and open the dialog, something like this dynamically by calling the showErrorInDialog method

```
showErrorInDialog: function(err) {
     this.error_message = err.message;
     this.error_detail = err.detail;
     this.$.error_dialog.opened = true;
}
```

But, the problem is, the paper-dialog width is only considered as per the width of h2 tag, e.g.

if h2 is "Error" and "p" is "There is an error with the connection, please check.", then paper-dialog width is as per the "Error" text in h2 only.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I have a similar issue but inside paper-dialog element i have an image. I don't know whats happening too..

Comment: I have added this to github https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3877. Hope, someone replies

Comment: Good job ! I will reply to this with my similar problem soon !